# .gitignore can't just ignore upper case and only commit lower case folder on Mac OS X

Tags: git

How to let only `Bin` folder ignore and let `bin` commit to git?  `[B]in/` will both commit `Bin` and `bin`.

I also tested `Bin`,`Bin/` in `.gitignore`, both `Bin` and `bin` are ignored.
I just want to commit bin and ignore Bin folder.

How to solve it? My os x disk isn't a case-sensitive filesystem

Comment: I don't think this really has anything to do with git.  Like you say, the OS X file system is case insensitive.  "Bin" and "bin" are identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I ignore every Bin folder myself in each folder:

```
    # Ignore everything in this directory
*
# Except this file
!.gitignore
# Except folders
!*/
```